# Array is [] when page is loaded

Tags: angular-material, angular-cli

I'm trying to find out why the array is [] even if I call the API in ngOnInit() method, but if I press next page button on my page the the array isn't anymore equal to [].
What is it strange for me is that if I use

```
*ngFor="let item of users"
```

it will show, without problems.

**TS file:**

```
export class DisplayAccountsComponent implements OnInit {
  // MatPaginator INPUT
  length: number;
  pageSize = 1;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [1, 5, 10 , 25, 50];

  users: User[] = [];
  activePageDataChunk = [];

  constructor(private _displayAccountService: DisplayAccountsService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllUsers();
    this.activePageDataChunk = this.users.slice(0, this.pageSize);
    console.log(this.users);
    console.log(this.activePageDataChunk);
  }

  onPageChanged(e) {
    const firstCut = e.pageIndex * e.pageSize;
    const secondCut = firstCut + e.pageSize;
    this.activePageDataChunk = this.users.slice(firstCut, secondCut);
    console.log(this.activePageDataChunk);
  }

  getAllUsers() {
    this._displayAccountService.getAllUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.users = data;
        this.length = this.users.length;
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

**And also HTML file:**

> ```
> <div *ngFor="let user of activePageDataChunk">
>    <p>{{user.firstName}} | {{user.lastName}} | {{user.email}}</p> 
> </div> 
> <mat-paginator [length]="length" [pageSize]="pageSize"
> [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" (page)="onPageChanged($event)">
> </mat-paginator>
> ```

As I said, when page is loaded users, activePageDataChunk are equal to [], but if I press next page, the variables are not anymore equal to [].
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAllUsers()` makes an async request. The line `this.activePageDataChunk = this.users.slice(0, this.pageSize);` will be executed before the async request has completed and therefore `this.users` and also `this.activePageDataChunk` will be empty arrays. Once the request completes it will populate `this.users` with data and upon clicking the next page button this line `this.activePageDataChunk = this.users.slice(firstCut, secondCut);` will populate the `activePageDataChunk` for the first time with data, hence you will be able to see data on clicking next page.

To solve this problem you could just change your code to the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._displayAccountService.getAllUsers().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.users = data;
      this.length = this.users.length;
      this.activePageDataChunk = this.users.slice(0, this.pageSize);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```